# Using Howler to play an MP3 with the play() method?

Tags: javascript, typescript, audio, howler.js

In [this Typescript Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-rlhobl?file=src%2Fmain.ts) if `autoplay` is commented out, the sound does not play, and I am expecting it to since `play()` is called:

```
const mp3: string = `https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3`;

var sound = new Howl({
//  autoplay: true,
  loop: true,
  volume: 100,
  format: ['mp3'],
  src: [mp3],
});
sound.play();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like there's no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` header served for the MP3 file. I added that header in DevTools and the music plays.

Comment: Hmmm .... Strange because with `autoplay: true` it also plays ...